# unable to close popever of autocomplete when using with modal from next ui in react

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, nextui

When utilizing autocomplete functionality within a modal and subsequently opening the popover, if no value is selected or if there is no click interaction inside the popover, it fails to close.

i want it to close when i click out side without selecting any value.

Comment: **Please add few more details like**, example : *There is a modal in which there are this components Input, Button etc.*, You may add some of your code if it doesn't contains any sensitive data.

Comment: Follow this issue for more informations => https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui/issues/1987#issuecomment-1817335810